# How to call a java gRPC service using HTTP/1.x request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, grpc, grpc-java

I have a gRPC service written in Java. I want to call that service using a RESTful web service. From my searches I have come to know that gRPC uses HTTP/2.x and I would need a reverse proxy server; but I don't know how to implement it. I am looking for a wrapper which can consume a gRPC service using REST APIs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is called gRPC-JSON transcoding.

Envoy provides an [implementation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter) as does Google with [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding) if you're deploying to Google Cloud.